# How to copy a file and paste into another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy a file from external drive and paste it into my excel, I can able to browse a file but I cant paste those values into a new sheet...in a same excel
here my code :

```
Dim fileStr As String
Sub GetOpenFile()

fileStr = Application.GetOpenFilename()
Worksheets("Sheet2").TextBox1.Value = fileStr

End Sub
Sub Button3_Click()

Workbooks.Open fileStr
ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to paste to the active sheet without having copied anything to begin with. Also, the active sheet probably isn't the sheet you want to paste to anyway.

Try this instead:

```
Sub Button3_Click()

Dim wbToCopy As Workbook

Set wbToCopy = Workbooks.Open(fileStr)
wbToCopy.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:H100").Copy

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").PasteSpecial

wbToCopy.Close

End Sub
```

`ThisWorkbook` always refers to the workbook that your macro is running in